# React-Native axios https

Tags: react-native, axios

How does react-native use self-signed certificates for HTTPS requests?

```
axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: headers,
        data: params,
        timeout: timeout,
        // httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false }),
    })
```

Comment: Could you be more specific with your question and title?

Answer (score 0):

You may try below :

**NPM  :  react-native-ssl-pinning**

for more info : [npmjs.com/package/react-native-ssl-pinning](http://npmjs.com/package/react-native-ssl-pinning)

Comment: It's no use to me.

Comment: Awwwww, I though you need this, or can you explain a bit more!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enable SSL pinning on the iOS part for my React Native Application using [TrustKit](https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit).
I am also using Axios to make server interactions.
There are two ways to implement TrustKit, by code or by using Info.plist. I have done using the Info.plist and you can find the implementation for the same below:

1. Add and install TrustKit in your podfile. (`pod 'TrustKit'`)
2. Open your Info.plist as Source Code add the below code to it.

> 

```
<key>TSKConfiguration</key>
<dict>
    <key>TSKSwizzleNetworkDelegates</key>
    <true/>
    <key>TSKPinnedDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>yourDomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>TSKPublicKeyHashes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public key 1</string>
                <string>public key 2</string>
            </array>
            <key>TSKPublicKeyAlgorithms</key>
            <array>
                <string>TSKAlgorithmRsa2048</string>
            </array>
            <key>TSKIncludeSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>TSKEnforcePinning</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

**Important things to note:**

1. `TSKSwizzleNetworkDelegates` needs to be set to true.
2. `yourDomain.com` is the base URL for your API.
3. `public Key 1` and `public Key 2` are the public keys for your API. You can get the pubic keys for any public domain [here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)
4. `TSKEnforcePinning` can be used to enable / disable SSL pinning by setting it to `true` / `false` respectively. (Incase you wish to enable/disable it temporarily)
5. For more details, please check out [TrustKit Documentation](https://datatheorem.github.io/TrustKit/documentation/Classes/TrustKit.html)